# Powershell Quotes

Tags: powershell, quote

I am trying to play around with echoing out specific path of a file using a csv file with input to use as variable.

So far I got something as simple as this,

```
$input = Import-Csv 'C:\Folder\file.csv' -Header "User"
echo 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\'$input.User'.txt'
```

The output is

```
C:C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\
Tom
.txt
```

My desired output is:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\Tom.txt
```

How would I do something like that?

Comment: [Read this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) and stop using `$Input` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you can utilize a [string subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) to accomplish your goal (note double-quotes as single-quotes indicate a string literal which do not expand variables):

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Folder\file.csv -Header User

foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    "C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\$($row.User).txt"
}
```

Or string concatenation:

```
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\' + $row.User + '.txt'
```

Or string formatter (this method takes an array of arguments to the `-f` operator; [useful article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/)):

```
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\{0}.txt' -f $row.User
```

Or variable expansion:

```
$user = $row.User
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\$user.txt"
```

---

footnote: using `echo` (alias for `Write-Output`) is unnecessary since any output not "captured" (by using redirection or variable assignment) will be output to the success stream (i.e., the console).  See [this document about streams and redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Burainu Glad to be of service.  I've added some additional documentation to the answer.